# Getting different values in 2d array after being passed to function

Tags: c

I am trying to pass a 2d array into a function that will check if the main diagonal of the array are all the same values (returning 1 if true and 0 if not). I am given a text file where the first line is the size of the matrix and the next lines are the matrix values.

While in the main function, the array is properly defined and I get the right value when I print out an index of the array, but for some reason when I pass the array to the checkDiag function I get really weird values, the first row is right but all the other rows give values ranging from 0 and 1 to numbers in the millions (the numbers don't change so I doubt they are memory addresses)

```
#include <stdio.h>



int checkDiag(int matrix[][100], int size){

    int checkTrue = 0;

    for (int k = 0; k < size-1; ++k) {

        if(matrix[k][k] == matrix[k+1][k+1] ){
            checkTrue = 1;
        } else{
            checkTrue = 0;
        }

    }
   printf("index 1 1 (funct): %d\n", matrix[1][1]);

    return checkTrue;
}




int main(){
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("matrix1.txt", "r");
    int size;
    fscanf(fp, "%d", &size);

    //printf("%d\n", size);
    int matrix[size][size];

    int i, j;

    for (i=0; i<size; ++i)
        for (j=0; j<size; ++j)
            fscanf (fp, "%d", &matrix[i][j]);

    printf("index 1 1 (main): %d\n", matrix[1][1]);



    int result =  checkDiag(matrix, size);


    printf("%d\n", result);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Text file:

```
3
4 5 6
7 4 9
3 6 4
```

The value I get for the function print it 0 while the value in the main print is 4 which is correct.

Thanks.

Comment: use `int checkDiag(int size, int matrix[size][size]){`

Comment: Also note that in your ```checkDiag``` function ```checkTrue``` will always be the value of the last check. You should return false immediately when the check is false and return true at the end of the function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `checkDiag` makes an assumption that the second dimension is always 100 what is not a case for an array declared as:

```
int matrix[size][size];
```

Use:

```
int checkDiag(int size, int matrix[size][size]) { ... }

...

int result =  checkDiag(size, matrix);
```